# Phpacademy OOP login and register part 8/23 function error() on a non-object line 56

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I am currently following the tutorial [in this video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PaBWDOBFxDc&list=PLfdtiltiRHWF5Rhuk7k4UAU1_yLAZzhWc&index=9) and I am getting this errors and I don't know what is happening here. I already follow the code in the tutorial and check all the comment and also the Q&A of the people that face problem before, and it also didn't solve my problem.

The error that I get is like following:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function error() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\ooplr\classes\DB.php on >line 56

Here is my code in db.php for line 45-65

```
public function action($action,$table,$where =array()){
        if(count($where)===3){
            $operators=array('=','>','<','>=','<=');

            $fields  =$where[0];
            $operator=$where[1];
            $value   =$where[2];

            if(in_array($operator,$operators)){
                $sql="{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$fields}{$operator} ?";
                if(!$this->query($sql,array($value)) -> error()){
                    return $this;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function get($table,$where){
        return $this->action('SELECT *',$table,$where);
    }
    public function error(){
    return $this->_error;
}
public function query($sql,$params =array()){
        $this->_error =false;
        if($this->_query =$this->_pdo ->prepare($sql)){
            if(count($params)){
                $x = 1;
                foreach($params as $param){
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x,$param);
                    $x++;
                }
            }
            if($this ->_query->execute()){
                $this->_result=$this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count=$this->_query->rowCount();
            }else{
                $this->_error =true;
            }
        }
```

This is the index.php which I run the query that cause that error stated

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

$user = DB::getInstance()->get('users', array('username', '=', 'alex'));

if(!$user->count()) {                          
echo 'No user';
} else {
echo 'OK!';
}

?>
```

init.php which I already check all the details that connect to database is correct

```
<?php
session_start();

$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'host'=> '127.0.0.1',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password'=>'',
        'db' => 'ooplr'
        ),
    'remember' =>array(
        'cookie_name' =>'hash',
        'cookie_expiry' =>604800
        ),
    'session' => array(
        'session_name' => 'user'
        )

);

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once 'classes/' .$class. '.php';

});

require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';

?>
```

this is the error that i get now 
[image: 1st error that get]

I check all the typo, database is fine, still can't figure out the what's wrong in line 56 of DB.php Any idea about this?

EDIT:after change this line

```
if(!$this->query($sql,array($value)) -> error()){
```

to this line

```
if(!$this->query($sql,array($value))->_error{
```

I get the error as shown in image below:

[image: error]

This is not the error that I get before.

Comment: Simple, `query()` does not contain a method called `error()`, presuming its pdo please show the db class that contains `query()`

Comment: Where's `query` method definition?

Comment: plus a quick scan of the tut its `if(!$this->query($sql,array($value))->_error` not a function `error()`

Comment: hi i update the function query in the question..tq @LozCheroneツ

Comment: and i tried the line that you provide,but still doesnt work...

Comment: @LozCheroneツ i get this error when change it to the line you provide Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN) in C:\wamp\www\ooplr\classes\DB.php on line 57

Comment: The indentation in the code you have provided is inconsistent (`public function action` starts off with two levels of indentation). I would start by fixing that first. Also, if you load this code into an IDE, I suspect it will identify the problem immediately.

Comment: Ah, and your latest change (`if(!$this->query($sql,array($value))->_error{`) is missing a closing round bracket. Always close what you open! Again, an IDE will really help here.

Comment: thanks for your help here,i do what you mention,but the error is return back to the error that shown before,as i update the error that before any modify of the code.@halfer is it anything i can do??

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a return at the end...

```
public function query($sql,$params =array()){
    $this->_error =false;
    if($this->_query =$this->_pdo ->prepare($sql)){
        if(count($params)){
            $x = 1;
            foreach($params as $param){
                $this->_query->bindValue($x,$param);
                $x++;
            }
        }
        if($this ->_query->execute()){
            $this->_result=$this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count=$this->_query->rowCount();
        }else{
            $this->_error =true;
        }
    }

  return $this;
}
```